# Out of curiosity, how many people here know how regular expressions are compiled?

Tags: regex, language-theory

I'm going over this in my theory class, and I'm curious as to how many people here know what regular expression compilation actually *is*. I've looked online, and it seems to me that this is a more archaic topic that I thought it was.

So yeah, who here knew before reading this question that a regular expression compile is performed by converting the regex to an epsilon-nondeterministic finite automaton? Who has no clue what that is?

Comment: Possibly better on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) on account of being a poll of programmers rather than a question with a programming answer.

Comment: Well, I don't think they'd like this question there either. "Who does not know this?" is a rather hard to answer meaningfully...

Comment: As a matter of fact most implementations actually *don't* compile to finite automata. Most regex dialects in use today can match languages that are not regular (and thus could not be matched by a finite automaton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very simple and elegant little regular expression compiler in C that Rob Pike wrote and Brian Kernighan describes in Chapter 1 of O'Reilly's [Beautiful Code](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780596510046).  It's pretty easy to learn from.  Also compiler courses cover it: token types can be defined with regular expressions.  So I imagine this knowledge isn't terribly rare.

Comment: That was a backtracking interpreter -- it did not compile to an automaton.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I guess I'll be the first one to admit that, although I took a compiler's course a couple years ago and know the general principle of it, I think I would need to bring out the "Dragon Book" again and read up some more on the subject if I were actually asked to write the code that does this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I knew it had something to do with finite state machines, but nothing beyond that. Not really a subject I wanted to delve into... I suspect it's nasty under the hood. Not many people on SO seems how to use regular expressions at all, nevermind understand how they work.